# "Share a link to this question via e-mail, , , or ."

Tags: support

Recently I've noticed that at the bottom of questions, there is a rather odd message:

[image]

I imagine it's supposed to say something like "...via email, Twitter, Reddit, or Facebook", but it seems like those other options are missing. I think that either other options should be added or it should be shortened to just "Share a link to this question via email."

Comment: @Metool it is indeed, and doppelgreener's new answer explains why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You guessed right, it usually says this:

[image: Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.]

Your exact scenario has been [reported before on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215219/152515). [The cause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196366/facebook-playing-hide-and-seek) is that you probably have an ad blocker or privacy extension that's filtering out any social sharing links.

Comment: I do indeed have Adblock Plus installed and disabling it does bring back the words. Thanks for diagnosing the problem!